# Magento 2: Why Magento copy product images in pub static cache directory?

Tags: magento2, media-images

While I upload a image in Magento. Image path was like **/001/21525-A-1000.jpg**

But Magento is rendering images on front-end from this directory:

```
example.com/pub/media/catalog/product/cache/image/e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe/2/1/21525-a-1000.jpg
```

So now as per my understanding this image is twice on my server.

Is this standard of Magento? **OR** Why Magento copy images in static cache directory?

Answer (score 2):

Short story: Yes, this is normal. in some cases you might see even more than 2 of the same image.
Long Story: In frontend, magento does not display the exact images you upload for various reasons.
The most important reason is that the image may require resizing when displayed.
There is no point to display a large image in the product list for example.
The resizing mechanism also takes into account some other factors beside size (transparency, quality, watermark, ...). The values for these parameters are concatenated into a string and then `md5` applied on that string gives you the `e9c3970ab036de70892d86c6d221abfe` you see in your image path.
So the image is processed on runtime if it does not exist and in frontend you see the processed image.

Answer (score 0):

The product images in the cache folder is not an exact duplicate of original image, but a **resized** version of the original that will be used by Magento according to its need (small image,medium, etc).